# AJAX on dropdown change PHP

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I try to use Ajax (my first time) and i don't know what i am doing bad. I have two files: home.html and ajax.php

On first one (home.html) i have this

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#Client_ID').live('change', function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url     : 'ajax.php',
                type    : 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data    : $('#myform').serialize(),
                })
            .done(function(data) {
                 for(var id in data) {        
                              $(id).val( data[id] );
                 }

            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='myform'>
     <select name='Client_ID' id='Client_ID'>
       <option value=''>Select</option>
       <option value='1'>Client 1</option>
       <option value='2'>Client 2</option>
     </select>
     <input type='text' name='address1' id='address1'>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my AJAX.php file it's

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-blog-header.php');

global $wpdb;
$clientid = $_POST['Client_ID']; // Selected Client Id
$result = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM wp_com_plantillas WHERE id=$clientid" );
$addr1 = $result->asunto;
$arr = array( 'input#address1' => $addr1);
echo json_encode( $arr );
?>
```

On database connection i use wordpress global var `$wpdb`.

To test **ajax.php** i change `POST` by `GET` and load url like ajax.php?client_id=1 and result it's ok, but when i test it on home.html, when dropdown change, input don't fill.

Thank you so much

Comment: When you debug this in the browser, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Stepping through the `done` callback in the debugger, is it doing what you expect?  Side note: That looks like a SQL injection vulnerability in that PHP code, you'll probably want to use prepared statements instead.

Comment: @David i  don't know how to this, but if  put an alert inside onchange function, it's executed. About SQL injection, it's a simple test, on my project i try to avoid this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Wordpress, consider taking a [look in this article that explains how to properly declare ajax on Wordpress](http://www.paulund.co.uk/using-ajax-wordpress)

Also, make usage of your Developer Tools, if you use Chrome. Pressing `F12`, you can see a tab named Network. Every request that your page does, it will be logged there. If you want to filter only AJAX requests, click on filter button then select `XHR`. Each line is a request and each request, when clicked, can provide information about the response. Check if that response is working, if response code is actually 200.

Comment: thank you so much to tell me how to debug this, i don't know this ;). Ajax returns on debug `code`input#address1: "Street" but it's not change on input field

Comment: Now it's working looking debugger. I change done: by success and it's works. I accept your answer because it's helped me to see it ;) Thankyou so much